# Fitting an exponential curve through scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, exponential

I am starting to use R and have a bit of a problem.
I have a dataset containing 20 points where leaf temperature and respiration is measured called ADC_dark.

I expect an exponential relationship where an increase in leaf temperature results in increased respiration
Then I plotted an exponential curve through this graph:

```
ADC_dark %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Tleaf, y=abs_A))+
    geom_point()+
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = log(y)~x)+
    labs(title="Respiration and leaf temperature", x="Tleaf", y="abs_A")
```

[image: Respiration-Leaf temperature in R]

This is not looking very good. The formula matching this line is y = -2.70206 * e^(0.11743*x)

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(ADC_dark$abs_A) ~ ADC_dark$Tleaf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0185 -0.1059  0.1148  0.2698  0.6825 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -2.70206    0.51255  -5.272 5.18e-05 ***
ADC_dark$Tleaf  0.11743    0.02161   5.435 3.66e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5468 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6213,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6003 
F-statistic: 29.54 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 3.659e-05
```

When I use the same data in excel I get this:
[image: Respiration - leaftemperature excel]

As you can see the intercept between these suggested exponential relationships differs.
Just looking at the pictures I would say that excel is doing a better job.

How can I 'train' R to make a better fitted curve through my data, or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you fit inside `ggplot2` start smooth using `log(y) ~ x` it occured that scales of your data points and fitted line are different. Basically you plot `y` and `log(y)` at the same `y` scale and since `y > log(y)` for any positive `y` your fitted plot shifted lower than your data point.

You have several options like to tweak axises and scales, or just use `glm` generalized linear model with log link instead of `lm`. In this case the scales would be presevered, no additional tweaking.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
ADC_dark <- data.frame(Tleaf = 1:20, 
                       abs_A = exp(0.11*x - 2.7 + rnorm(1:20) / 10))

ADC_dark %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Tleaf, y = abs_A))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", type = "response", formula = y ~ x, method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "log")))+
  labs(title = "Respiration and leaf temperature", x = "Tleaf", y = "abs_A")
```

Output:

[image]